# Internal error while installing eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse

When I launch 64 bit setup of Eclipse Neon for my 64 bit linux I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be blank
    at org.apache.http.util.Args.notBlank(Args.java:68)
    at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.setupProxy(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:950)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.setupProxies(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:884)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.handleArchiveRedirection(SetupCoreUtil.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.createResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.<init>(SetupWizard.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.<init>(SetupWizard.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.Installer.<init>(Installer.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

I couldn't find any solution for this problem after searching a lot.

This is the output of my `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-2-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you edited any config file in eclipse folder if Yes what are they?

Comment: @SanjitKumarMishra No, I haven't edited any file. All I did was download [this file](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R1/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz), extract it using `tar xvf ...` and then run `eclipse-inst`.

Comment: see this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1498. it might help you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, and fixed it by creating an environment variable called `http_proxy` and setting it to a meaningful value.

Fresh environment, but failed:

```
$ ~/Downloads/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst
```

Fresh environment, but worked (I fired up Fiddler as a proxy):

```
$ export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8888
$ ~/Downloads/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst
```

I noticed that the proxy was never used, but simply checked for existence.